# How do I get the selected value from a select box, from inside an Iframe, and display it on the outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, iframe

I have this select box in HTML, and the page it's on is being loaded into another page (both on my website) through an iframe. I want to be able to get the selected value from the select box (inside the iframe), and display it on the outside. Here's some code I've pieced together, but I don't know if i'm doing it right:

```
<script>
$('#iframe').contents().find('#cds').change(function() {
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on'; 
    $("twitter").attr("id", url);
});
</script>
```

Any advice?

**To Clarify**

- My `<select>` element is in the `iframe`
- I want to display the selected value outside the `iframe`
- The source of the `iframe` is on the same domain as the page into which it is loaded

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you receiving any errors? Note that the iFrame must be on the same domain...

Comment: They're both on the same domain, but nothing's happening, so I don't know if my script is wrong, or if its the wrong way to go about doing this.

Comment: `$('twitter')` should have a `.` (class) or `#` (ID) in front

Comment: And why are you setting an ID to a URL

Comment: @mplungjan - reverse that; URL to an ID :)

Comment: @mplungjan It's due to the way the page is being accessed in my adobe air app, this is the only way I can do it.

Comment: @Mottie post that as an answer

Comment: @Mottie I tried that, but it didn't work. Here's the code (I apologize for my noobness): `<script>

$('#iframe').contents().find('#cds').change(function() {
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on'; 
    $('#twitter').attr("id", url);
});

</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but

```
$("twitter").attr("id", url);
```

should probably be:

```
$(".twitter").attr("id", url);
```

---

Update: Try this code... you need to detect if the iframe has loaded as well ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/baEb9/2/))

```
$(function () {
    // define this here because we're changing the ID
    var $twitter = $('#twitter');
    // bind to select inside iframe
    $('#iframe').on('load', function () {
        $(this).contents().find('#cds').change(function () {
            var selectVal = $(this).val();
            url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';
            $twitter.attr("id", url).text(url);
        }).change(); // trigger change to get initial value
    });
});
```

Also, since we're changing the ID of twitter, we need to save that jQuery object.

Comment: Just one more thing (I apologize), but I'm trying to do the same thing with a jwplayer playlist on the same page, but the layout is different, (as it's more of a dynamic div than a select box) how would I do it with this? Here's the structure: `<div class="jw_playlist_playlist"><div class="jw_playlist_item even">item</div><div class="jw_playlist_item odd">item2</div></div>`

Comment: Since the div is dynamic, you'll need to find out where it gets updated and use a callback or triggered event to get those updates. It might be better to open a new question with the code and more details about how the playlist is updated.

Comment: Hmmm I'll have to do that tomorrow. Thanks!